# Popup preview of a textarea using a PHP function

Tags: javascript, popup, textarea, preview

I'd like to make a popup preview of a textarea, using a PHP function inside the popup.

Let's say you type "Hello world" in the textarea, then you click "preview" and you get your text converted to "Hey you" by a PHP function in a popup (of course the function is not that simple, that's the reason why I can't adapt this in pure javascript).

Is it possible to do so ?

I know it could easily send the form to an intermediate page, but I must keep the form in background... that's why I need a quick preview on fly.

I did the following:

```
        function PreviewMe() {
          var newWin = window.open("", "_blank");
         newWin.document.write("<html><body>"+document.getElementById('myText').value+"</body></html>");
          newWin.document.close();
        }
```

and

```
<textarea id="myText"  ... /> 
<input type="submit" ... onclick="PreviewMe();">
```

Obviously it works without reformatting anything, so how to reformat this result in the popup  please ?

Would it be possible (and mayber a better option) to use XMLHttpRequest ?

Thx !

Comment: you can't with simply php, you need javascript e/o client side programming language to show the popup

Comment: Do you think it could be done with a XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: i mean... the event of showing popup can't be done by php, then if you use a php script and then show the results  in a javascript popup that it's up to you :)

Comment: since the question is **Popup preview of a textarea using a PHP function** my answer is NOT POSSIBLE :)

Comment: Ok :) Maybe I used the wrong words, by "using a PHP function" I didn't meant to create the popup using PHP, but "to interact inside the popup with PHP"

Comment: So, what you need is probably a XHR request, you call a script -> the script returns you what you want -> javascript elaborates the response (this means you can easly get and manipulate data by the XHR)!

Comment: javascript -> php ->javascript my friend :)

Comment: I will try to use the XMLHttpRequest object then. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, it was by far easier in the end.

In case it might help others, here is what I've done.
Js function became :

```
function PreviewMe() {
    var xhr = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        } else {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
    } else {
        alert("XMLHTTPRequest not supported...");
        return;
    }
    xhr.open("POST", "page.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        } 
    };      

    xhr.send("var="+document.getElementById('myText').value+"");
    return;
}
```

Of course `page.php` includes my PHP function, `show` is the id of the div where the result is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you should use an `XHR` request to  send data to a script which will return you data to be manipulated on the client side.